# split timeseries by 24h periods in pandas, but not at 00:00:00

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

with :

```
data = {'date':['2019-02-23 00:00:00', '2019-02-23 03:00:00', '2019-02-23 06:00:00', '2019-02-23 09:00:00', '2019-02-23 12:00:00', '2019-02-23 15:00:00', '2019-02-23 18:00:00', '2019-02-23 21:00:00', '2019-02-24 00:00:00', '2019-02-24 03:00:00', '2019-02-24 06:00:00', '2019-02-24 09:00:00', '2019-02-24 12:00:00', '2019-02-24 15:00:00', '2019-02-24 18:00:00', '2019-02-24 21:00:00'], 'foo':[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18]} 
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

for bar in df.groupby(df.index.date):
    #doing some complex stuff with foo data
```

I'm trying to split this timeseries by day, but not at 00:00:00 like it's done both by `df.groupby(df.index.date)` or `df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='1D'))`, but for example from 10:00 to 10:00 the day after. I tried `Ioffset` in `Grouper`, but it change only labels.

=> Please, is there any nice way to do that ?

Thxs.

Answer (score 1):

The following example will group rows by date starting from 10am to 10am

what it does is it subtracts 10 hours for all dates which will change time upto 10AM of next day to current day. So grouping by only date part of this changed dates will group rows from 10am current date to 10am next date

```py
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"])

df.groupby((df["date"] - pd.Timedelta(10, "H")).dt.date).apply(lambda g: g.assign(group=g.name))
```

Comment: Wow. Honestly, I don't understand the line. But it works perfectly, and it's a very nice one-liner. Thxs Dev.

Comment: @MericNESSANGE plz find detail explanation in the edited answer. If the solution worked for you plz consider marking the answer resolved and upvote

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Series.dt.hour`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.hour.html) + [`Series.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) to detect the time change around 10. Then using [`Series.cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) you can create the groups you need.

Note that here you have used [`Series.le`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.le.html) and [`Series.ge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ge.html) instead of simply [`Series.eq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) because there may not be data where the time is equivalent to 10

```
df['date']=pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
n=10
groups=(df['date'].dt.hour.ge(n)&df['date'].shift().dt.hour.le(n)).cumsum()
print(groups)
```

---

```
0     0
1     0
2     0
3     0
4     1
5     1
6     1
7     1
8     1
9     1
10    1
11    1
12    2
13    2
14    2
15    2
Name: date, dtype: int64
```

---

```
for i,group in df.groupby(groups):
    print(group)
```

---

```
                 date  foo
0 2019-02-23 00:00:00    1
1 2019-02-23 03:00:00    2
2 2019-02-23 06:00:00    3
3 2019-02-23 09:00:00    4
                  date  foo
4  2019-02-23 12:00:00    5
5  2019-02-23 15:00:00    6
6  2019-02-23 18:00:00    7
7  2019-02-23 21:00:00    8
8  2019-02-24 00:00:00   11
9  2019-02-24 03:00:00   12
10 2019-02-24 06:00:00   13
11 2019-02-24 09:00:00   14
                  date  foo
12 2019-02-24 12:00:00   15
13 2019-02-24 15:00:00   16
14 2019-02-24 18:00:00   17
15 2019-02-24 21:00:00   18
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't understand Dev Khadka's code, so I wrote my own, which does the same but in much more lines:

```
def split_series_by_hour(
    series: pd.Series,
    split_hour: int,
    split_frequency='24H'
) -> list:

offset = pd.Timedelta(hours=split_hour)

series_offset = series.copy()
series_offset.index = series.index - offset

grouped = series_offset.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq=split_frequency))

# Now `grouped` is an iterable where each element is a tuple,
# the first item is the group label (the start of the group interval),
# the second item is the sub-series for that group.
# Shift the 'time' in the result back by the offset to get the original times

sub_series_list = []


for group_time, group in grouped:

    group.index += offset

    sub_series_list.append({'time': group_time + offset, 'sub_series': group})

return sub_series_list
```